# Protecting linear ssDNA inside a yeast cell

Tags: cell-biology, yeast

This is kind of a multi-part question :)

Basically, I want a linear single-stranded polydeoxynucleotide to exist inside an *S. cerevisiae* cell cytoplasm for a long time without being digested. As far as I understand, the main danger to a linear DNA are 5' and 3' exonucleases (am I right?). So, the first question is:

**What particular exonucleases digest ssDNA in yeast? What other enzymes do? Maybe something involved in defence against viruses? Which of them, if any, can be safely knocked out (i.e. are not absolutely crucial to the survival and reproduction of the cells)?**

The rest of the question is about protecting the 3' end of the molecule against exonucleases (assuming they aren't knocked out). For the application I have in mind, "unnatural" modifications of DNA (like phosphorothioate bonds or 2' modifications of sugars) are unacceptable. Only 3' modifications of the last nucleoside are possible. In particular, I am considering something like:

[image: 3 prime end]

Where X = -O-, -S-, -NH- or phosphodiester, and R can anything that's either something small (-H, -alkyl, -acyl, ...) or something big but connected by a long spacer (say, a protein on a PEG tether).

**Can an effective 3' end protection be achieved this way?**

The problem is, according to [this](https://international.neb.com/tools-and-resources/feature-articles/the-effect-of-nucleic-acid-modifications-on-digestion-by-dna-exonucleases), 3' modifications are generally bad at inhibiting exonuclease activity, but I can either use them or knock out nuclease genes (the latter is less preferred).

Comment: Would a [locked nucleic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locked_nucleic_acid) work?

Comment: No. I should have probably defined "unnatural" as modified sugars or phosphodiester bonds. A bridged ribose doesn't work as R, too, because it's bulky.

Comment: Can you [edit] in some background about why you want to do this? Is it important the the ssDNA not be digested or that there be a high steady state level of the ssDNA? If the latter, there are alternative strategies that would allow you to achieve your desired ends without extensively modifying the yeast genome or expensively modifying the ssDNA. ——— The problem I see is that yeast also has enzymes with ssDNA **endo**nuclease activity (and 5' exonucleases), so 3' end protection (or complete KO of 3' exonucleases) probably wouldn't be sufficient, again depending on your goals ...